# What is the probability hat two particular players verse in Wimbledon if it begins with $16$ players?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Sixteen people play in the quarter-finals at Wimbledon. The winner of the quarter-finals play again in the semi-final to decide who enters the finals. **What is the probability that two particular people will play each other if the tournament begins with 16 players?**

So I have so far (case 1 + case 2) = verse player in quarter OR verse player in semi = $\frac{1}{15} + \frac{14}{15}...$

I'm not sure what else to include in the second case

Also the third part of the question asks **What is the probability when $2^n$ players begin?**

The worked solutions show $\frac{1}{2^n-1}+\frac{2^n-2}{2^n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\right)^2\:=\:\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ which I cannot get. Even symbolab doesn't show the same simplification. As with the previous question, I do not understand the $\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\right)^2$

Comment: I guess you are assuming that all 16 players are equally good, so the results are random? (In reality the probability that the two best players will meet should be close to one.) As $15$ matches will be played, I guess the probability is $15/\binom{16}2=2/15$. By the way, there actually *is* a verb "verse" in English, but it doesn't have a meaning that makes sense in the title of your question.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{1}{8}$. The first part of the question was 
"assuming all eight players are equally likely to win a match" so I assumed all players would also be equally likely to win a match concerning 16 players

Comment: Oops. $15/\binom{16}2$ was right, but that works out to $2/16$ not $2/15$. Duh.

Comment: Why is it 15 matches? If theres 16 people wouldn't it be 8(quarter) + 4(semi) = 12 rounds?

Comment: @bof And why do you put the matches to be played OVER the $16C2$? I assume 16C2 is referring to choosing the two particular players

Comment: There are $\binom{16}2=120$ pairs of players, and $15$ of those pairs will meet. So I guess there are $15$ chances in $120$ that the pair we bet on will meet. I'm not sure this reasoning is correct.

Comment: Hmmm its a massive simplification to the worked solutions $\frac{1}{7}+\frac{6}{7}(\frac{1}{2})^3 = \frac{1}{4}$ Could it be luck?

Comment: I see where you are coming from. But where do you get the 15 from?

Comment: $15$ is the number of matches played: $8+4+2+1=15$ or more simply, there are $16-1=15$ losers, one loser per match.

Comment: Number the $\binom{16}2$ pairs of players from $1$ to $120$ and let $X_i$ be an indicator variable for the event "the $i^\text{th}$ pair meets". I was worried about the fact that those events are not independent but I guess that's OK because additivity of expectation doesn't require independence. So $E(X_i)=p$, the probability that those two meet, is a constant, by symmetry: identical players, random pairing. Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^{120}X_i$. Then $E(X)=120p$ by additivity of expectation, but plainly $E(X)=15$, so $p=15/120=1/8$.

Comment: The question is not well written. How do $16$ people play in the quarter-finals? What is the format? If it is by elimination, you have $4$ quarter-finals with $8$ players, $2$ semi-finals with $4$ players and a final with $2$ players.

Comment: Thank you @bof I understand. However, I still don't get the 15. I get everything else and your method is way simpler than the worked solutions: What confuses me is why there are 4 "groupings" $8+4+2+1$, If there are only two games (quarter and semi = 8 + 4). If you continue and say the 2 is for the final, where does the one come from? Alse the question doesn't state that the finals match was actually played.

Comment: I see what's confusing you. I didn't read that part of the problem; I just assumed it was describing a normal [single elimination tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-elimination_tournament) with 16 players. There are 4 rounds; 8 matches (16 players) in the first round, 4 matches (8 players) in the second, etc. Of course the final is played, otherwise what's the point? There are 2 players in the final, 4 in the semi-final, 8 (not 16) in the quarter-final. Poorly written problem. Is that from a textbook?

Comment: Yes its from a textbook. I agree its a poorly written question. It seems even the worked solutions do not know what to do. I'll just leave it and pretend its a single-elimination tournament as the solution still matches with your working.